# Import javascript in html with npm

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to add this github [component](https://github.com/dbushell/Pikaday) to my project.
I followed the instruction to use npm

```
npm install pikaday --save
```

and the pikaday and moment modules are in the node module folder, but when I run my html file:

```
<body>
<input type="text" id="datepicker" value="9 Jun 2016">
<script src="pikaday.js"></script>
<script src="moment.js"></script>
<script>
    var Pikaday = require('pikaday')
    var picker = new Pikaday({
        field: document.getElementById('datepicker'),
        format: 'D MMM YYYY',
        onSelect: function() {
            console.log(this.getMoment().format('Do MMMM YYYY'));
        }
    });
</script>
</body>
```

I got the following error:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/pikaday.js 
(index):14 GET http://localhost:3000/moment.js 
(index):17 Uncaught ReferenceError: Pikaday is not defined
    at (index):17
```

I change the path to

```
<script src="/node_modules/pikaday/pikaday.js"></script>
```

but got the same error

Comment: you need to use a module bundler like webpack or browserify to load the modules

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your going to need to make that available as a static file. If you're using express:

`app.use('/static/pikaday/pikaday.js', express.static('./node_modules/pikaday/pikaday.js')`

Then in your html:

`<script src="/static/pikaday/pikaday.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know is if you'll use by npm, you'll need to use other framework like webpack to build once javascript file with your whole js code, because the node_modules dir should not be deployed to your server.

The snippet `var Pikaday = require('pikaday')` doesn't work in browsers, only over the node.js server.

if you don't want to build a bundle with your js, you may just download the files and configure into your assets